# What is a concise notation for a range based for loop iterating over a few tuples

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there a simpler (shorter) way to write this code snippet as a loop:

```
for (auto [a, b]: {pair<int, int>{1, 2}, pair<int, int>{3, 4}})
  foo(a, b);
```

Preferably making the initializer list as close as possible to this form, which doesn't compile:

```
for (auto [a, b]: {{1, 2}, {3, 4}})
  foo(a, b);
```

Comment: *cough* macr *cough* o...

Comment: `do { foo(1, 2); foo(3, 4); } while (false);` ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 You are legally correct! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might do the following in C++17 thanks to deduction guide:

```
for (auto [a, b]: {std::pair{1, 2}, std::pair{3, 4}})
    foo(a, b);
```

or even

```
for (auto [a, b]: {std::pair{1, 2}, {3, 4}})
    foo(a, b);
```

Comment: Beautiful! Since I usually dispense with `std::`, your solution is literally the most concise and flexible one.

Comment: Along these lines: `for (auto [i, j, k]: {tuple{.1, .5, 5}, tuple{.4, .5, 6}})`

Comment: @PaulJurczak - You can go one shorter. Only the first item must explicitly be a pair. The second one will be deduced based of the first.

Comment: @rubenvb What do you mean by *scales terribly*? Compile time penalty?

Comment: @Paul each element in the list needs a typename prepended. But then I hadn't see StoryTeller's comment which invalidates my observation. Never mind :).

Answer (score 5):

As C++ is a strongly typed language, there are limits to the fuzziness you can expect from the compiler deduced types. Two levels of unspecified braces is an example of this.

You can make it shorter by using a simple typedef:

```
using pair_list = std::initializer_list<std::pair<int, int>>;

for (auto [a, b]: pair_list{{1, 2}, {3, 4}})
  foo(a, b);
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3591e988b50265e5). You can optimize/choose the temporary's type as you wish.

Comment: *Oh*. And there I was mucking around with classes and deduction guides.

Answer (score 2):

There is a shorter way to do it which involves construction of a temporary `std::map`.

You can do something like this:

```
for (auto [a, b]: map<int, int>{{1, 2}, {3, 4}})
        foo(a, b);
```

This compiles. See it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc7d430554760070).

Or as @Jarod42 suggested, you can use `std::initializer_list<std::pair<int, int>>` as well.

```
for (auto [a, b]: std::initializer_list<std::pair<int, int>>{{1, 2}, {3, 4}})
```

You will have to type a bit more. :)

Comment: `std::initializer_list<std::pair<int, int>>` should do the job too.

Comment: @Jarod42: Thanks. Updated.

Comment: `map<int, int>` looks good, but will probably be a performance killer in an inner loop.

Comment: @PaulJurczak: Yeah, I was going for the shortest. :)

Answer (score 1):

Still a bit verbose, but this template might be of help:

```
template <class T>
constexpr auto asPairs(std::initializer_list<std::pair<T, T>> args)
{
   return args;
}
```

It can be instantiated and used like the following.

```
for (auto [a, b] : asPairs<int>({{1, 2}, {3, 4}}))
    foo(a, b);
```